# Cor() runs in console but has error when kitting

Tags: r, correlation

The code below runs within the console and i get an output of 0.57

```
cor(days_sleep_tracking$TotalMinutesAsleep, days_sleep_tracking$count_days_sleep_tracking , method = "spearman")
```

However, but when i try to knit the rmd file to HTML i get the following error message.

```
Error in cor(days_sleep_tracking$TotalMinutesAsleep, days_sleep_tracking$count_days_sleep_tracking,  : supply both 'x' and 'y' or a matrix like 'x'
Calls: <Anonymous> ... withVisible -> eval_with_user_handlers -> eval ->eval ->cor
In addition: Warning message:
Expected 2 pieces. Additional pices discarded in 413 rows[1,2,...]
Execution halted
```

| count_days_sleep_tracking (int) | TotalMinutesAsleep (dbl) |
| --- | --- |
| 25 | 360.2800 |
| 4 | 294.000 |
| 3 | 652.000 |
| 5 | 417.0000 |

I have ensured that loading of the stats library is included in the rmd file.

I have writtent the same code to calculate correlations in another table which knits correctly. I assume the issue may realte to the table and data types but from what i can see the data types are the same across each table

Any help would be appreciated

Comment: That error happens if the second column does not exist i.e. is NULL. Must check that.

Comment: Greetings! Usually it is helpful to provide a minimally reproducible dataset for questions here so people can troubleshoot your problems (rather than a table or screenshot for example). One way of doing this is by using the `dput` function on the data you are using and pasting the output into your question. You can find out how to use it here: https://youtu.be/3EID3P1oisg

Answer (score 1):

The table was created by merging two separate tables.

Re-merging the tables under a different name appears to have solved this problem